# Treegrid doesn't persist selectedRows

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I'm using lightning treeGrid in my lightning Component but once I collapse Grid and re-expand it, selected values are no longer selected.

Component:

```
<aura:attribute name="gridData" type="Object" />
<aura:attribute name="selectedIds" type="Object" />

<lightning:treeGrid
                            aura:id="treegrid_Diagnosis"
                            columns="{! v.gridColumns }"
                            data="{! v.gridData }"
                            selectedRows="{!v.selectedIds}"
                            expandedRows="{! v.gridExpandedDiagnosisRows }"
                            keyField="name"
                            isLoading="{! v.isLoading }"
                            ontoggle="{! c.handleRowToggle }"
                            onrowselection = "{!c.getSelected}"
                            />
```

Controller:

```
handleRowToggle: function(component, event, helper) {
        var rowName = event.getParam('name');
        console.log(">>> rowName... "+rowName);

        var isExpanded = event.getParam('isExpanded');

        // does the component have children content for this row already?
        var hasChildrenContent = event.getParam('hasChildrenContent');

        // the complete row data
        var row = event.getParam('row');    

    }
```